# change text of a TextView by horizontal page swinging

Tags: android

In my App,I have a page with 10 horizontal scrollable buttons on top, and a TextView' under them. by clicking on each button,the text of TextView changes.
I want to change text of 'TextView' by horizontal page swinging too.
how can I do that?(I have only one 'TextView' for all Buttons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are implementing swipping. If for instance you are using some sort of ViewPager you could setOnPageChangeListener(...) implementing this interface notifies you every time scrolling and swipping happens